Weak formulation of the biharmonic equation
The biharmonic equation is
$\Delta^2 u = 0$.
Tutorials show that the stiffness term in the weak formulation is:
$\int \langle\Delta \varphi_i, \Delta \varphi_j\rangle$
However, FEM implementation uses
$\int H\varphi_i : H\varphi_j$
where $H \varphi$ is the Hessian of $\varphi$, and ':' is a double-dot product.
Which one is it?

$\{ \varphi_i \}$ are basis functions of the Sobolev space:
$u = \sum_i \varphi_i u_i$
$\varphi_j$ are test basis functions.
For example, see sec 6.2 in
[Crane23 "DISCRETE DIFFERENTIAL GEOMETRY- AN APPLIED INTRODUCTION"]
https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/Projects/DDG/paper.pdf

What is $\varphi$ ? How does it relate to $u$?

I added detailed.

Assuming appropriate homogeneous boundary conditions and a bounded domain with smooth boundary, we have
$$
\int_\Omega Hu:Hv~\mathrm{d}x = \int_\Omega \sum_{j,k=1}^n u_{x_jx_k}v_{x_j x_k}~\mathrm{d}x = \sum_{j,k=1}^n \int_\Omega u_{x_jx_k}v_{x_j x_k}~\mathrm{d}x = \\- \sum_{j,k=1}^n \int_\Omega u_{x_jx_kx_j}v_{x_k}~\mathrm{d}x = \sum_{j,k=1}^n \int_\Omega u_{x_jx_j}v_{x_k x_k}~\mathrm{d}x = \int_\Omega \Delta u \Delta v~\mathrm{d}x.
$$
The integration by parts is an application of Green's identity:
$$
\sum_{j,k=1}^n \int_\Omega u_{x_jx_k}v_{x_j x_k}~\mathrm{d}x = \sum_{k=1}^n \int_\Omega \nabla u_{x_k}\cdot \nabla v_{x_k}~\mathrm{d}x = -\sum_{k=1}^n \int_\Omega \Delta u_{x_k} v_{x_k}~\mathrm{d}x + \int_{\partial\Omega}v_{x_k}\nabla u_{x_k}\cdot\hat{n}~\mathrm{d}s. 
$$
Homogeneous Dirichlet conditions guarantee the boundary integral is zero, so we then rewrite our itnegral and apply Green's identity again:
$$
-\sum_{k=1}^n \int_\Omega \Delta u_{x_k} v_{x_k}~\mathrm{d}x = -\int_\Omega \nabla(\Delta u)\cdot \nabla v~\mathrm{d}x = \int_\Omega\Delta u\Delta v~\mathrm{d}x - \int_{\partial\Omega}\Delta u\nabla v\cdot\hat{n}~\mathrm{d}s.
$$
Homogeneous Neumann conditions or Dirichlet conditions on $\Delta u$ are needed in order for this second boundary integral to be zero and we are done.

Please explain the third equality. The RHS looks like the second part of integration by parts, but it's missing the first part.

It is one of Green's identities, which is higher dimensional integration by parts. The term that is missing is an integral over the boundary involving $\nabla v\cdot \hat{n}$, which must be zero for this equality to be true. This typeof boundary condition is common in biharmonic problems and is likely being assumed in this implementation.

I assume you refer to Green's first identity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities), but I don't see how you applied it; can you be specific?
About the boundary conditions; the test function $v$ vanishes on a Dirichlet boundary; that's all.
Finally, here is an example, where it doesn't hold: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-N0JYvMpVOaUcbYKd-DTMzYvFRvw4OfL/view?pli=1

Edited my answer to include the uses of Green's identity. As for the example you linked, it doesn't even have a domain; the integrands are equal pointwise so none of this is even needed. For the biharmonic equation, you need more than just homogeneous Dirichlet conditions in order to obtain this weak form.
